# How to add Punch In at quick launch orangehrm

Tags: dashboard, orangehrm

How to add Punch In/Out in quick launch bar in dashboard in OrangeHrm?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to ..\symfony\plugins\orangehrmDashboardPlugin\config folder.

there will be two files links.yml(quick access links user dashboard) links_admin.yml(quick access links admin dashboard).

You can edit the links here or you can add new one.